# I can't create another ForeignKey using Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small Django Project, I would like to create a second ForeignKey in the same model, but it doesn't work after the migration I don't see the field in my table contact,

**this is my Models ( i have a Custom User Model and work fine )**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'   
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

**This is my class Contact ( as you can see I try to add a foreign key called user )**

```
from django.db import models
from list.models import List
from users.models import CustomUser

class Contact(models.Model):

    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="list")
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="user")

    greeting = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=60)
    company = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=60)
    phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=60)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

What i try to do :

1. Each user can have Contacts
2. Each Contact depend on a list

Comment: I see some indentation issues in your code (class declaration shuld be not indented). Besides that, the way you declare your foreign keys is ok. Have you already run `makemigrations`  and `migrate`?

Comment: yes i did ( python manage.py makemigrations )  and migrate too

Comment: indentation  is just in Stackoverflow by the way

Comment: it can be my CustomUser may be ?

Comment: now i get column "user_id" does not exist

Comment: Do you have the console responses to `makemigrations` and `migrate`? It should contain info telling the new field was added or, in due case, an error.

Comment: You are getting such error because the field wasn't created by `makemigrations`-`migrate`. But we need the error message to locate the problem.

Comment: now i get column "user_id" does not exist, which it means i think there is no user_id in my CustomUser Model

Comment: The error is now i get column "user_id" does not exist

Comment: Nope, the error is because the column has not been created

Comment: what should i do please ?

Comment: Have you ran showmigrations? Have you verified, in your db, that all your migration files have been applied? Also, does makemigrations work? It sounds like you might have inconsistent migrations. Try removing the user field, run makemigrations, migrate, add the field back in, then run makemigrations and migrate again.

Comment: i did that, and the migration works fine if i remove user field. @PaulTuckett

Comment: still have the same issue

Comment: If you don't have any data in your db, I would try removing your db, create it again, remove all of your migration files, then run `makemigrations/migrate`. With all your models the way you want them to be (with the user FK). It seems like a migration file is messed up, or at some point something got changed/modified inside one of them.

Comment: @PaulTuckett  same issue again with another database ( new one )

Comment: Did you completely remove all of your migration files?

Comment: yes i did  , and i changed the DB

Comment: Have you specified an `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser"` in your settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fixes the problem but
you should not name your model field "list"
because "list" is one of python's reserved keywords. When you redefine it Unexpected things can happen

Comment: I tested using "list" as a model name and it didn't cause any issues.